# Which is the preferred Authentication Library for an Outlook Web Add-In

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, adal.js, office-js-helpers

Does Microsoft prefer ADAL.JS or Office-JS-Helpers for Authentication?

Our app registrations are all on AAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your choice of libraries that you are using Implicit Flow. We are phasing out use of office-js-helpers. This [Azure AD page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) seems to endorse msal.js.

Comment: Thanks.   I'm seeing lots of different solutions, and it's not always clear where I should be focused.